# How to detect the namespaces in a foreign XML document using MSXML2?

Tags: xml, vba, xslt, xpath, namespaces

When working with XML using MSXML2, it's pretty well documented that for any XPath queries to work, you need to define the `selectionNamespaces` property. However, this is only a straightforward fix if you always know what the namespaces are. I'm writing a module in VBA that I hope to be able to use to parse all the Office XML formats, and I'd like a function that can arbitrarily define the namespaces for documents as I load them.

At present, I've found the following isn't a bad first stab:

```
Public DoDefineNamespaces(strRootNodeName As String, strFilePath As String, ByRef oMyDoc As MSXML2.DomDocument60)
    Dim oRootNode As MSXML2.IXMLDomNode
    Dim oMyDoc As MSXML2.DomDocument60
    Dim oAttribute As MSXML2.IXMLDomNode
    Sim strNamespaces As String

    Set oMyDoc = New MSXML2.DomDocument60
    oMyDoc.Load strFilePath
    Set oRootNode = oMyDoc.SelectNodes("./*[name()='" & strRootNodeName & "']")
    For Each oAttribute In oRootNode.Attributes
        If oAttribute.Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" Then 
            strNamespaces = strNamespaces & oAttribute.Xml
        End If
    Next oAttribute
    oMyDoc.SetProperty("SelectionNamespaces", strNamespaces)
End Sub
```

With a couple of subtle changes for dealing with the default namespace. However, this won't work very fell with XML like the following:

```
<?xml>
<root xmlns:t="MyFirstNS">
   <t:object1>
       <r:object2 xmlns:r="MySecondNS" />
   </t:object1>
</root>
</xml>
```

Aside from traversing, is there an approach that might be better than mine for dealing with this kind issue = i.e. any namespace not defined in the root node? Ideal would be an XPATH 1.0 expression that will select all xmlns attribute nodes even when the namespace they exist in has yet to be added to SelectionNamespaces, or help building an XSLT transform that will produce a nodeset with the namespaces of a document.

Comment: What does that mean: "that will select all xmlns attribute nodes even when the namespace they exist in has yet"?

Comment: That's what I get for starting writing the question and then getting interrupted! Corrected to make sense - full sentence was supposed to finishe "... yet to be added to SelectionNamespaces".

Comment: What do you plan to do with the namespaces once you have them? If these are truly unknown namespaces, then I'm not sure how you will use them in queries.

Comment: It's not so much that they're unknown as that they should be unknown as far as the module is concerned. The idea is that the same code could be used in principle with Excel, Powerpoint, Word, Visio, etc. etc. files, each of which might use subtly different namespaces, and only one of which is relevant now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine all namespaces *used* in the document, use this XPath 1.0 query:

```
/*/namespace::*
```

This will include duplicates.

For XPath 2.0, you'd go for

```
distinct-values(//*/fn:namespace-uri())
```

instead as the namespace axis is deprecated. Both only return namespaces actually in use (and omits the ones which are not used). This query already removes the duplicate namespaces.

Anyway: if you don't care about the namespaces, it might be more reasonable to just ignore them. In XPath 1.0 you have to use the wildcard axis step and do a name test in a predicate. To match all elements `<foo/>` with arbitrary namespaces, use `//*[local-name() = 'foo']` respectively `//*:foo` in XPath 2.0.

Comment: The `namespace::` axis is useful here - hadn't come across it (really should have done), but `distinct-values()` looks like it's XPath 2.0 only - it throws an Unknown Method when executed in VBA on MSXML2 which only supports XPath 1.0 functions. Still might point me in the right direction for a simple XSLT transform template...

Comment: It is; was too late at night when I wrote the answer. Well, omit it and do it on your own in VBA; I guess throwing all namespaces in a hash table would be the most reasonable way...

Comment: Probably what I'll need to do - certainly faster than re-learning XSLT. Which thinking about it would ALSO need a distinct function that probably doesn't exist... Thanks for axis pointer, though!

Comment: You should even be able to do some hack with a predicate that tests if the namespace already occurred before, but this will probably have n^2 runtime and not be optimized by XPath 1.0 implementations. Something like `/*/namespace::*[not(preceding::*/namespace::* = .)]`. Didn't test it though.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look. Failing that I'll probably write an exclusion loop - i.e. 1) Select all namespaces anywhere, 2) Take the first one, add to dictionary, and add a filter along the lines of `*namespace::*[namespace::*<>'just_added_namespace']`. Rerun the filter until no namespaces get returned and treat as done. Not sure whether that would be faster or not than using `preceding::` - one has more work to do, but the other does that work in a horribly slow scripting language. Will investigate and see!

Comment: I don't know what data structures VBA offers, but "dictionary" seems fine. Just add the namespaces with same key/value (the namespace); if you find it again, all you will do is overwrite it. If you're done, fetch all (now distinct) values.